# Error creating directory: Input/output error

Tags: partitioning

I have a very important data on my external hdd and i can't create new folder,docoment,copy,cut,paste or any thing.

can't check disk using gparted or ntfsfix or fsck

```
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

[image]

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: i tried to open my disk on windows but windows not detect it

Comment: If Windows doesn't detect it, you may have a corrupt partition or a hardware malfunction. Have your tried running testdisk on it?

Comment: @Dorian no how can i do this?

Comment: @Dorian do you mean i recover data to another drive and then reformat ??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: -  You can not mount dynamic drives with ntfs-3g.  You can check with `gdisk -l /dev/sdb1` if it is.  - Don't use fsck (a linux tool for ext filesystems) on a windows filesystem. - If  this is not a dynamic disk this is a **Windows** problem, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I backup my files to another disk using [Redo image](http://redobackup.org/) and then format and restore my file to my disk.